# Edit a file in several emacs sessions

Tags: emacs

Emacs says

> You want to modify a buffer whose disk file has changed since you last
>   read it in or saved it with this buffer.
>
> If you say `y` to go ahead and modify this buffer, you risk ruining
>   the work of whoever rewrote the file. If you say `r` to revert, the
>   contents of the buffer are refreshed from the file on disk. If you say
>   `n`, the change you started to make will be aborted.
>
> Usually, you should type `n` and then `M-x revert-buffer`, to get the
>   latest version of the file, then make the change again.

Why does it recommend

> Usually, you should type `n` and then `M-x revert-buffer`, to get the latest version of the file, then make the change again,

rather than

> say `r` to revert, the contents of the buffer are refreshed from the file on disk?

Are the two really different? They seem the same to me?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen these suggestions. What version of emacs is this?

Comment: GNU Emacs 23.3.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 3):

> You want to modify a buffer whose **disk file has changed** since you last read it in or saved it with this buffer.

This means that someone, somewhere, changed the file you are currently active with before you saved your chances, graphically it would be like this:

```
              — Current file on Disk
            /
File-orig —
            \ 
              — Your saved buffer (*)
```

Both can be different. If you select <kbd>r</kbd> it will safe your buffer for later and **reload from the disk**.

```
              — Current file on Disk —
            /                          \ 
File-orig —                              — Current buffer (*)
            \ 
              — Your saved buffer
```

So you can review the changes were made to the file since you last read it from the disk.

Now, when you do <kbd>r</kbd> and then <kbd>M-x revert-buffer</kbd>, this is what happens:

```
              — File on Disk —
            /                  \ 
File-orig —                      — Buffer read from disk ——— (*) Applied your changes over the one on the disk
            \                                           / 
              — Your saved buffer —————————————————————
```

*Voila!* The changes made on the disk and yours are now in the same file, both have been merged. If you know Git, the above should be similar to merging branches.

If you only select <kbd>r</kbd> the changes you made would be lost. If you select <kbd>y</kbd> the changes made by the other person would be lost. That's why this is recommended.

Comment: Thanks. how does Emacs do so that "both have been merged"?

Comment: @Tim it applies your changes as if you were editing the file on disk instead.